# Efficiently compute this Table of NullSpace

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, linear-algebra, sparse-arrays

I have two $(2n,2n)$ matrices, $A_1$ and $A_2$, and I would like to compute 
$$\ker(A_1^p A_2^q -I)$$ for $p,q\leq 2n$.

Both matrices are orthogonal and have exactly four non-zeros values on each line and columns (sparse matrices). This is what a typical $A_1$ looks like, for $n=5$:

$$A_1=\dfrac{1}{2}\ \left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
 -1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 1 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Here is the code to produce $A_1$ and $A_2$:

```
n = 5;
mat = 1/2*{{1, -r,0,0,1,r},{-1/r, 1, 0, 0, 1/r,1}} ;
A1 = ConstantArray[0,{2n,2n}];
Table[A1[[i;;i+1,i-2;;i-2+5]] = mat,{i,3,(2n-2),2}];
A1[[;;2,;;6]] = 1/2*{{-1, -r, 1, r,0,0},{1/r, 1,1/r,1,0,0}};
A1[[-2;;,-4;;]] = 1/2*{{1,-r,1,-r},{-r,1,r,-1}};
A2 = A1 + SparseArray[{{1,1}->1,{2,2}->-1,{1,2}->r,{2,1}->-1/r},{2n,2n}];
r = 1;
A1 = SparseArray[A1//N]//Chop;
A2 = SparseArray[A2//N]//Chop;
```

The problem I face is that I am intersted in these kernels for matrices corresponding to $n\approx 500$, and doing:

```
Table[NullSpace[MatrixPower[A1,p].MatrixPower[A2,q] -
        IdentityMatrix[2n]], {p,1,2n}, {q,1,2 n}]
```

takes a long time... I tried precomputing all the matrix powers to avoid computing them several times, but it was even worse, probably because of the memory calls (despiste the `SparseArray` structure).

Any idea how I could speed up this computation?

Note that I also tried to simplify the problem on the math side (see [this math.SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1812363/invariant-vectors-of-an-bm-with-a-b-orthogonal-matrices)) without success.

Note that $A_1^p A_2^q$ remains a sparse matrix (see comments), as it can be illustrated:

```
tab = Table[MatrixPower[A1, i].MatrixPower[A2, 12] 
  // MatrixPlot[#, ImageSize -> Small] &, {i, 1, 50, 5}]
GraphicsGrid[{tab[[;; 5]], tab[[6 ;;]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think `NullSpace[]` respects sparsity in the exact case, which is why it's slow for a sufficiently large size.

Comment: @J.M. What do you mean by _exact case_ (here I use `N`)? Do you see any workaround? Thank you.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed the `N[]`. In any case: did you try looking at what `MatrixPower[A1,p].MatrixPower[A2,q]` looks like for small `n` and slightly larger `p` and `q`? I suspect some severe fill-in is happening during the powering.

Comment: @J.M. No, it does not fill-in for the following reason. $A_1$ and $A_2$ are both orthogonal with entries in $\{-\frac{1}{2},0,\frac{1}{2}\}$. Hence, they both have exactly 4 non-zero values on each row/column (each row/column is unitary). When we do the product of such matrices, the result is also such a matrix, because each element is the sum of an even number of products of halves... I am not sure if that's understandable, but I recommend `MatrixPlot`ing $A_1^pA_2^q$, it's quite interesting (the diagonal band kinds of reflects... hard to explain with words...).

Comment: Alright, I'll investigate later; I was hazarding a guess based on previous experience with a similar application (but in retrospect, none of those matrices I was dealing with were orthogonal, IIRC).

Comment: @J.M. I added an illustration in the question :)

Comment: @J.M. unfortunately mathematica can currently (V 10.4.1) not not exploit sparse structure for `NullSpace` computation.

Comment: @user21, I thought as much, but hesitated to say it outright; it's hard to maintain sparsity with SVD.

Comment: I think the more request of that nature are made to higher the priority is going to be to get it implemented.

Comment: For `n == 500`, I get `ByteCount[A1] == 138 312`. Let's assume `ByteCount[MatrixPower[A1,p].MatrixPower[A2,q] - IdentityMatrix[2n]]` is roughly this number for all `p, q`. If we want to have a `Table` with $2n \times 2n$ such matrices, we need 138 Gb of RAM. Of course the output of `NullSpace` is not $2n \times 2n$, but still this does not seem feasible...

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Well, the output of `NullSpace` is typically a few vectors of $2n$ elements. So that's easily 100 times less than $2n\times 2n$ (with $n=500$), so should be feasible with, say, 8Gb of RAM (I think).

Comment: @user21 And can you think of other ways without using `NullSpace` (with e.g. `SingularValueDecomposition`) ?

Comment: No, not that I can think off, but I am not a linear algebra expert. Try to simplify your question be eliminating the `ParallelTable` to exclude that this is part of the slowness.

Comment: Well actually, `NullSpace[]` does use SVD when given an inexact matrix, so I'm not optimistic. But you should do your own experiments.

Answer (score 4):

The most I've managed to improve the speed is about a factor of 2, but I thought I would share my attempt anyhow.

First, let's just compute the identity matrix once, instead of once each iteration step:

```
id = SparseArray[IdentityMatrix[2n]];
```

Second, since we are going to need *all* the powers of both `A1` and `A2`, we can gain some speed by simply bumping the power on each iteration in the `Table`. You can see that this approach makes sense by comparing the timing of `MatrixPower[A1,10]` to `MatrixPower[A1,100]`.

Third, we can use `QRDecomposition` since it seems to be faster than all the other decompositions (LU, SVD, `RowReduce`), at least on my machine. The null space should be spanned by the components of Q corresponding to tiny values on the diagonal of R.

The code:

```
Block[{a1p,a2p,tab,q,r},
a1p = A1; a2q = A2;
 nullspacebases = Table[
    tab = Table[
      {q, r} = QRDecomposition[a1p.a2q - id];
      a2q = a2q.A2;
      Pick[q, Chop[Diagonal[r]], 0],
      {q, 2 n}
      ];
    a2q = A2;
    a1p = a1p.A1;
    tab,
    {p, 2 n}
    ];
 ]
```

I've only been able to test this for `n = 80`, so there is still some patience needed :p Note that for `n = 80` the `Table` in the OP which uses `NullSpace` gives `SingularValueDecomposition::cfail` and `NullSpace::cfail` messages, while `QRDecomposition` gives none, so I'm not sure what to trust here...

Comment: You could use `id = IdentityMatrix[2 n, SparseArray]` - but that does not make a big difference here.